# How to make pg_dump generate upsert statements in Postgres 9.5

Tags: postgresql

I want to dump a database and restore dump on another database that could have data in it. How do I make `pg_dump` generate `insert on conflict update` statements instead of just insert statements? I use Postgres 9.5

Comment: Short answer: you can't.

Comment: duh! the limitations of Postgre, this is possible in mysql

Comment: Anyone tracking if this has changed since 2016? Would be VERY useful for me right now.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PostgreSQL database restore using pg_restore as incremental data without overwritten or drop existing tables - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67107087/postgresql-database-restore-using-pg-restore-as-incremental-data-without-overwri). (The conclusion is the same: it is not possible out-of-the-box as `pg_dump` won't generate `INSERT ... ON CONFLICT ... DO UPDATE` commands.)

Answer (score 18):

With PostgreSQL 12 and later, you can use `--on-conflict-do-nothing` switch of `pg_dump`. See [docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-pgdump.html).

Example:

```
$ pg_dump test --table=lifehack --section=data --column-inserts --on-conflict-do-nothing

[...]

--
-- Data for Name: lifehack; Type: TABLE DATA; Schema: public; Owner: filip
--

INSERT INTO public.lifehack (id, content) VALUES (1, 'Brush your teeth twice a day.') ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING;


--
-- PostgreSQL database dump complete
--
```

Comment: I spent a lot of time finding this solution. +50 upvote

Comment: ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING doesnt seem to update the conflicted row but just skip that INSERT. Can someone help how to update the entire row when there is a conflict ? Something like ON CONFLICT DO UPDATE (all entries in the insert)

Comment: @Yogi, you can't, you must say what to update. 

`CONFLICT (id) DO UPDATE date=EXCLUDED.date .....`